# wordpress how to display Gaussian Blur images when user not login

Tags: css, wordpress, blur, gaussian

my question is wordpress how to display Gaussian Blur images in post-content if a user not login, when login display normal images

It may need to change the css like this
.post-content .notlog{-webkit-filter: blur(0.5em);filter: blur(0.9em);}

how to write Determine statements in theme's functions.php file, and how to add css to theme's css file?

sorry, my english is poor, can some one help?

Answer (score 0):

First you should research [child themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) as modifying the theme's functions.php and styles.css directly is not a good idea. When a user is logged in the HTML body element has the class 'logged-in' so you can add the css selector 'body:not(.logged-in)' to restrict the blur css rule to be used only when no user is logged in.

Comment: thanks, also my css & html is poor, I can read, but it is hard for me to write, so if you can help me give me some specific code, just modifying the theme's functions.php and styles.css directly, then i test it, and think how to do this, thanks again